# Help identify and remove a weed

Tags: identification, lawn, weed-control

[image][image][image: Plant with small leaves]

I have noticed this weed taking over my lawn (I live in Texas) and parts have overrun my St. Agustine grass.

Any idea what it is and how to eliminate it?

Comment: Any chance of a top view of a triplet of leaves? (Flattened a bit). To see if it is Mexicano spp.

Comment: Yes, we need to know a little more: Does this species have a creeping stem and are the leaves on the photo fully developed or very young? Photos of flowers would be helpful too.

Comment: The plant does seem to have a creeping stem and I have not noticed any flowers.

Answer (score 1):

I say [Kummerowia striata](https://plants.ces.ncsu.edu/plants/kummerowia-striata/), but https://identify.plantnet.org/ finds Kummerowia stipulacea is more likely (73%)

[Kummerowia stipulacea](https://wiki.bugwood.org/Kummerowia_stipulacea):

> Kummerowia stipulacea is an annual freely branching herbaceous plant with upward pointing hairs. The plant can be procumbent to erect and can reach up to 24 in. (61 cm) in height. It has shallow taproots.

> Leaves are alternate, trifoliate, petiolate and up to 0.75 in. (4 cm) long.

[Kummerowia striata](https://plants.ces.ncsu.edu/plants/kummerowia-striata/):

> The stems are purplish with appressed white hairs that point downward.

> The alternate compound leaves are trifoliate with leaflets being ¼-1" long

[To distinguish](http://wildflowers.clockwork-orrery.com/2016/09/11/kummerowia-striata-vs-kummerowia-stipulacea/) especially pay attention to

> The leaves of each species are similar, but there are slight
> differences. The leaves of K. striata are a little narrower than those
> of K. stipulacea. Also, the margins of the leaves of K. stipulacea
> have conspicuous hairs, especially on younger leaves, whereas the
> leaves of K. striata have smaller, inconspicuous hairs or none at all.